# How to open native app to call with a phone number write?

Tags: swift, ios8

I have this for call:

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://thephonenumber"))
```

but this open directly the native app calling. I want open this but with the number write for I press the button call, not directly.

how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

According to the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

> Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app
>   does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.